# Clarification on Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge needed

Tags: pi-3b+, access-point

Regarding the detailed instructions for Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge here:

[Access point as WiFi repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89803/access-point-as-wifi-repeater-optional-with-bridge)

Since the raspberry pi 3 b+ has only one radio, I'm a bit confused on how this setup provides both an access point to another access point via wireless, whilst still providing a client wireless access.

Comment: **ap0** is a virtual interface created by `iw dev wlan0 interface add ap0 type __ap`

Comment: The "answer" you have given below is  not an answer. You should put it into this question and delete the "answer".Please read the first line in your screenshot: "**Put the SD Card into your RasPi and boot.**". Why should it be necessary to boot again? You are already doing the "**Next Step:** Full upgrade and reboot". Just read the line before you reboot. It doesn't help continuing with the next step before finishing the previous one. Please ensure that Checkpoint3 works direct after first boot.

Answer (score 0):

You write:

> I'm a bit confused on how this setup provides both an access point to another access point via wireless, whilst still providing a client wireless access.

It isn't right this way. An access point does not connect to another access point. It is only the client wireless connection that connect to another remote access point. The access point of the RasPi does not connect to anything. It only provides the possibility that other clients can connect **to** the RasPi. So you have two distinct functions:

- access point - provide connections to the RasPi
- client connection of only the RasPi to another remote access point/internet router

You can make only an access point or only a client connection. They are independent.

This is possible if the wifi chip supports it. If you look at the link you have used, at the section **Details - General** you will find:

> One problem is that we want to use the same device for a wifi client and for an access point. This must be supported by the wifi hardware. We can check this with
>
> ```
> rpi ~$ sudo iw list | grep -A4 "valid interface combinations:"
>         valid interface combinations:
>              * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1, #{ P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1,
>                total <= 3, #channels <= 2
>              * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1, #{ P2P-client } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
>                total <= 4, #channels <= 1
> ```
>
> The important part is `#{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP } <= 1`, but you can also see that **this is only possible on one channel**.

That it can only use one channel for both functions is respected to the fact that the RasPi has only one radio. The channel the access point uses is always the same than the channel the RasPi is connected to the internet router no matter what channel in the setup is defined for the access point.

And there are further restrictions you can read there.

Comment: So I guess I misinterpreted the first diagram which leads me to believe that ip address 192.168.4.1 (ap0) allows a mobile-phone to connect and that signal is repeated out through wlan0 with ip address 192.168.10.1.  The foregoing assumes the RPi can handle both signals, correct?  I need a wireless repeater then which this doesn't seem to be.  Followed instructions but could never gain access to the internet from ap-connected device.  I could ssh into the RPi and ping the internet via wlan0, but whenever mobile device attempted to connect to RPi it would connect but without internet access.

Comment: @jeffschips The RasPi can handle both signals and it can connect mobile devices on the access point to the internet. So it is working as a wireless repeater. Please follow the instructions at [Test access point as WiFi repeater](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/93636/79866) and tell me, which **Checkpoint** fails for you.

Comment: I get as far as Checkpoint 4 and then cannot access the Rpi via wifi.  I can remove the sd card and see it's files on my linux machine if that is helpful. Perhaps I can verify/change files on the SD card? Raspberry Pi 3 b+.

Comment: @jeffschips No, not removing the SD Card. Let's stay on the RasPi.**Checkpoint4** has 4 commands to check. Does all commands show similar results then shown? What ip address has wlan0 (third command)?

Comment: I mean after failure to connect, I can remove the SD card if you need me to access files therein.  Away from device now and will do as you say and post results here later today.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I ran through the steps from Checkpoint 3 up until Checkpoint 4.  Same results, as before: when I reboot after completing all the steps successfully in Checkpoint 3 there is no internet connectivity to the Rpi.

Comment: Can't add more information here as there is a limit but the ip address of wlan0 is 192.168.1.2. I also cat out the data in the commands given for the steps between Checkpoint 3 and Checkpoint 4 and the files are properly formed.  Running nmap 192.168.1.0/24 from a computer connected to the router shows no results for the Rpi but does show results for other connected devices.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a command to enable wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service?  I don't see that anywhere. . .

Comment: @jeffschips You wrote in a comment: "*... in Checkpoint 3 there is no internet connectivity to the Rpi.*". I do not understand why do you proceed with the next step to Checkpoint4. You must have internet connection before. At the beginning of the tests I wrote: **" I suppose you have a monitor, keyboard and mouse attached to your Raspberry Pi and have a DHCP server running on your local wireless network."** Is this true?

Comment: @jeffschips After Checkpoint3 you can read: **"Until now we have only done default setup. If you have some trouble then there is a general problem with your network. [Check How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/79866) and fix it."** Have you done it?

Comment: I *do* have internet connectivity up until *after* the sudo systemctl reboot command of Checkpoint 3.  So I can't proceed to Checkpoint 4.  I am stuck in Checkpoint 3 *with* internet connectivity until *after* rebooting as per the last instruction of Checkpoint 3. If the RPi is being assigned a different network ip address I would have discovered it with nmap.

Comment: @jeffschips Sorry, but I do not understand. For me it seems that you do not follow the instructions written down. On Checkpoint3 there is no command *sudo systemctl reboot* and there is no need to reboot. You have just booted the fresh flashed SD Card the first time. The only thing you have to do is to log in and check. There are hundreds of users where this is working. So please double check what you are doing different.

Comment: I posted the screenshot of the command to reboot from Checkpoint 3.  See above. Answer 2 please.

Answer (score -2):

The phrase written by you "*Next step full upgrade and reboot*" - that very phrase is placed between the end of checkpoint 3 and the commands to upgrade and reboot.  Why would you include those commands if you didn't want the user to proceed *from* checkpoint 3 in sequence *to* those commands?  Maybe I'm missing something here but I generally follow the commands in the order that they are entered.  If you don't want users to actually update and reboot, why would you have those commands there?  But okay, I get it, you don't actually want users to execute those commands.  I apologize for the back and forth.  Probably just a misunderstanding between languages.
And yes, checkpoint 3 works fine after initial reboot.  So exactly what then is the next step after completing checkpoint 3 (without rebooting, of course).

Comment: Again, please don't use answers as comments! Instead use comments. And I think it's time that you please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here. OK, you wrote: "*And yes, checkpoint 3 works fine after initial reboot.*". So your **wlan0** interface has an ip address and you can ping google.com, means you have a working internet connection. The next step is the "***Next step:** Full upgrade and reboot:*" with update, full-upgrade, reboot and so on as described.

Comment: As far as I can tell I can't add code snippets or images to comments, that's why I was using answers.  My bad.   I have already specified several times that I was able to get an IP address in Checkpoint 3 and access the internet, and that I cannot proceed to checkpoint 4 because the instructions are to do an upgrade and reboot between Checkpoint 3 and Checkpoint 4, which I do do and then after upgrade and reboot, I am locked out and cannot access the raspberry pi.  It would seem therefore, that we are going in circles.

Comment: To answer your comment You can always use your question to clarify your situation with code snippets or images. I have already suggested to do it. You still don't have read the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visited the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here. Note that we are not a discussion style forum and open ended invitations to brainstorm are not appropriate to the format.

Comment: You never told that you are locked out after upgrade and reboot before Checkpoint4. But this cannot be an issue because you have to use a monitor and keyboard/mouse attached to the raspi. I also wrote in bold letters that this is condition. Sorry, but if you don't follow my suggestions and don't read or understand what's written down, I cannot help you.

Comment: Well I thank you for your support.  If you see entry dated – jeffschips Feb 18 at 14:23  and your response to that on – Ingo Feb 18 at 15:23 you will see that I did, indeed, say I couldn't access the Rpi.  Anyway, I will move on from this.  I've learned a lot.  And thank you.